# Yii save data to different tables

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I need to save data collected from a single form to three different tables.
So my doubts are

1. How can I design the Model class (CformModel or CActiveRecord)??
2. How to design the view??
3. In Controller how can I save the data to different tables??

I need to manually validate some vales like md5 hash etc

Comment: do you mean from a single form to three different tables?

Comment: Yes, a single form and multiple table.And required operations such as  generate md5 hash and validate it against some fields etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to create three models. And use according model fields and save all three models.

In Yii one table - one model.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24593-one-model-to-access-many-tables-in-same-database-having-similar-structure/

Answer (score 2):

In your controller: saving your different models for different tables will look like:

```
$modelB=new Addresses;
$modelB->attributes=$sess['addresses'];
$modelB->save();

$modelC=new TenQs();
$modelC->attributes=$sess['tenqs'];
$modelC->save();
```

To render multiple models to one form you just keep listing the models in the render statement.

```
$this->render('create',array('modelB'=>$modelB,'modelC'=>$modelC));
```

That would work in your controller.  This example assumed Active Record.